# How do I edit project settings for an existing project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

*I'm new to Eclipse/Java/Android*

I can create a new project using the New Android Project wizard shown below.

However, if I wanted to go back and edit some of these settings after I click `Finish`, how would I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You settings are in:

- `.eclipse` file
- `.classpath` file
- `.settings` directory

So you could:

- open those files/directories and have a look
- create another project with the right settings and compare the two sets of project files.