# How do you open an existing .java file and compile it in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am just starting to consider using Eclipse, as I hear it is a very good debugging tool and excellent IDE. I have a .java file which I had written in JCreator and have saved in my Google Drive directory. However, I am having problems running this file within Eclipse. If I open Eclipse and then open my file, a few things happen. First, a .metadata folder appears inside my Google Drive. Second, the file opens, and I can edit and save changes. However, if I try to compile the file, I get a "Run As" popup window with the options "Ant Build" and "Ant Build..." Selecting either results in a "Build Failed" error.

I have a few questions:

1) What is the .metadata folder and why does Eclipse create it?

2) How do I open an existing .java file in Eclipse?

3) What is an "Ant Build"?

Sorry if these questions are very basic, but a search through online tutorials has only told me how to create and compile projects with Eclipse. If I start a project in Eclipse, then everything works fine, but otherwise, I can't get anything to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I do not know, but a simple Google search led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279992/should-i-regularly-delete-the-metadata-folder-from-the-eclipse-workspace-what) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996170/what-is-the-metadata-folder-in-eclipse-workspace) which might be of help;
2. I don't know if it is possible to just open a file without starting a project, but once a project has been started, it is relatively easy to import a file: File>Import, find the directory, check the files you want to import, select import directory and go ahead. Now I haven't managed to run a program with GUI after importing because apparently it has problems loading classes like `JFrame` because of a `restriction in the library`, but I have imported and run a simpler program; oh, and when you import, you select General, then File System;
3. Try googling for Ant Build. I fount a few sites mentioning "Apache Ant", which seems to be related to GUI building.